# how to fix this code if i have lower version of java?

Tags: java

I am creating a binary search tree but I have a error because in our school we have a lower version of java or should I say compiler jdk1.6.0_45 
how to fix this error?

this is the error if i run it in 1.6.0

```
  illegal start of type
  Node node = new Node<>(value);
```

how can I arrange this in order to run in a lower version?
ps. that is the only compiler that i can use

i have some example

this is not working in a lower version

```
Stack<Character> s = new Stack<>();
```

but this one is working

```
Stack<Character> s = new Stack<Character>();
```

Comment: With Java 1.6, empty diamond operator on the right side is not valid. But the main issue is probably about Node class. You don't say which library it's from. For many of them, Node is not generic, e.g. javax.xml.soap, org.w3c.dom, ...

Comment: when editing your question, please tag the edited part, i.g. start it with something like EDIT or UPDATE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior Java 1.7, the actual type parameter (`Character` in your examples) needed to be specified for all parameterized types (`Stack<Character>`).

From 1.7 and onward, the compiler is able to infer the actual type parameter in `new Stack<>()` to be `Character` because it knows that it is being assigned to a `Stack<Character>`; consequently, you do not explicitly have to state it when invoking the constructor.

Since you are using Java 1.6, both the variable declaration and constructor invocation need to specify the actual type parameter, yielding:

```
Node<Type> node = new Node<Type>(value);
```

where `Type` should be replaced by the actual type parameter of the `Node`.

Comment: As long as we don't know what library is Node class from, we can't state that Node is a generic one.

Answer (score 0):

I would download a JDK that is similar to the one used by your school from the Oracle website and compile using that.

Comment: is there any possibility that i can fix that one just like what I did in my example?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the previous versions of the java from java archives available at oracle site. Below is the link for this website.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/archive-139210.html

After download you will need some configurations to use this new version. 
If you are using command line than

> set classpath

If you are using eclipse following will be needed

> In the project build path configuration dialog, under the libraries
>   tab, you can delete the entry for "JRE System Library", click on "Add
>   Library" and choose the installed JRE to compile with. Some compilers
>   can be configured to compile at a back-level compiler version. I think
>   that's why you're seeing the addition version options.

Comment: sir this for my assignment in our school but unfortunately our  school only have a lower version I already have a the latest version of jdk.

Comment: is there any possibility that i can fix that one just like what I did in my example?

Comment: No need to call "Sir" we are all same over here. See its a temporary solution; and you will continuously face same issue. Just install lower version on you machine and resolve it for rest of the term.